# How can I get the url for current store when proxy is REST?

Tags: extjs, extjs4.1

I don't want reinvent the wheel, so I'm quite sure they have a method, on store (or proxy) to transform a rest proxy params into an url (for read action).

I want do the same, but I can't find any getUrl or something like it, and in rest the url is built with some configuration.

Any suggestion on what methods extjs uses? I'm quite sure they must do the same to run the ajax request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Ext.data.proxy.Rest` has a [`buildUrl()`](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.data.proxy.Rest-method-buildUrl) method:

> Specialized version of buildUrl that incorporates the appendId and
>   format options into the generated url. Override this to provide
>   further customizations, but remember to call the superclass buildUrl
>   so that additional parameters like the cache buster string are
>   appended.

Comment: I'm trying to use it but I'm having troubles with Operation object. It seems that I can't create one because I don't have a batch object correctly. Any suggestion about it?

Comment: I used this technique in the end, however the Operation you pass to buildRequest must not have filters/groupers/sorters properties set (it's not a problem because they aren't used to build the url).